# Most efficient Layouts implementation in Android(form layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

1. In general , how do you choose the types of layouts you use when working on a new design of a layout?
2. More specifically, if you have a a form layout (registration form for example) , how would you implement it in xml in the most efficient way?

[image: example of a form layout :]

My first assumption is to break it all to LinearLayouts. Each EditText and TextView(description) of the editText would be in a LinearLayout of its own that will be part of a bigger LinearLayout.
But is there a way to make it more efficient?

Comment: I choose the layout which offers me the **flattest possible** hierarchy design (meaning the **lower level of nesting**). Sometimes, I re-think my UI design.

Comment: Could you please explain it with the form layout example as mentioned above?
My idea of having nested LinearLayouts seems to be, in my opinion, as the worst solution( performance-wise) .
I'd like to understand what you mean by "flat" .

Comment: flat means the lowest number of nested layouts. "Completely flat" would be the top of performance, 1 layout only and the Views inside it. If it has to scroll, then this won't be possible. You would have a LinearLAyout, then a ScrollView inside it and then another layout in it. But, well, 2 levels is not that evil at all. For me, `the flatter, the better`.

Comment: Thanks. Just a small question : is there a better way to do the edittext forms (They have these purple "borders" but are white inside) than having a layout/imageview with purple background and another one with white bkacground on top of it with 1-2dp margins ?

Comment: Yes, sure. Use a backround drawable (either a ShapeDrawable, a StateList Selector or a 9 patch).